# Save three.js mesh to json file with ajax/php and reload

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to save a mesh from three.js to a json file and then reload it using the ObjectLoader. The json data seems to save fine but can't be loaded back in.

Here is the saving:

```
    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 100, 60, 40 );
    var material =new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x7D6236, shading: THREE.SmoothShading } );
    sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    var stringData = JSON.stringify(sphere.toJSON() );
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'savefile.php',
        data: {data: stringData},
        success : function(d){
            console.log('done');
        }            
     })
```

The saved json file:

```
{
"metadata": {
    "version": 4.4,
    "type": "Object",
    "generator": "Object3D.toJSON"
},
"geometries": [
    {
        "uuid": "04D4BA75-A09A-4EE2-AAB8-2E5A412A4368",
        "type": "SphereGeometry",
        "radius": 100,
        "widthSegments": 60,
        "heightSegments": 40
    }
],
"materials": [
    {
        "uuid": "EAC33171-BE69-4952-8C01-789220742F86",
        "type": "MeshPhongMaterial",
        "color": 8217142,
        "emissive": 0,
        "specular": 1118481,
        "shininess": 30
    }
],
"object": {
    "uuid": "C5BB28B4-F4FC-4BFE-9ADC-19D2B2B40D25",
    "type": "Mesh",
    "matrix": [
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        1
    ],
    "geometry": "04D4BA75-A09A-4EE2-AAB8-2E5A412A4368",
    "material": "EAC33171-BE69-4952-8C01-789220742F86"
}
}
```

The reloading:

```
var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
loader.load( 'mesh.json', function ( geometry ) {
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x7D6236, shading: THREE.SmoothShading } );
    sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add(sphere);
});
```

Error message when try to load:

```
TypeError: a is undefined
```

Comment: Use the unminified version of three.js and you will probably get a clearer error message

Comment: Thanks, it gives the error: "TypeError: sphere is undefined" and seems to trace to THREE.Sphere.prototype.copy()

Comment: Are you sure it's not to do with your `sphere` variable? Does the error report a line number?